# how to pass local variable from one function to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass this variable from one function to another function but there is some issues with this.

```
var url;
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
$("#ToBuyStep2").click(function(){

    if(ua.match(/MicroMessenger/i)=="micromessenger") {
        url=window.location.href;
        window.location.href = "http://www.juliyeah.com/wap/tmpl/order/weixin.html";
    }
})

function goBackUrl(){

    if(ua.match(/MicroMessenger/i)!="micromessenger") {

        window.location.href = "http://www.juliyeah.com";
    }
}
```

So I need to remember this url when the `ToBuyStep2` is clicked and pass this url to `goBackUrl()` function. These two function are called in different files so I cant combine them together.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
const functionGenerator = function() {
    let url = '';

    let result = {};

    result.ToBuyStep2 = function() {
        // you can access URL here
    };

    result.OnClick = function() {
        // you can access URL here
    };

    return result;
};

let temp = functionGenerator();

document.getElementById('whatever').onclick = temp.OnClick;
document.getElementById('stuff').someEvent = temp.ToBuyStep2;
```

Comment: Yes closures are exactly useful for this job.

Comment: @Redu yes, closures are the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage to set the "last url" and then, request it within your boGackUrl function: `sessionStorage.setItem('prevUrl', window.location.href)`. Keep in mind that after the location changed, your data is lost. But passing data into session storage, will make it available until the user closes the tab/browser.

Comment: the reason why I need to do this is because when users browse my website on the browser of wechat, wechat block paypal so that users cant see paypal plugin. So when they transfer to safari the session wont be the same I think.

Comment: You got to be kidding me... you want to pass details from one browser to another? Well, if that's the case, you might need to learn a little bit more about how web works...